# JsonB, JPA, REST, CDI, Generating incomplete JSON

Tags: java, database, rest, jpa, jsonb

i'm trying to get Jsonb objects from my DB. When try getting all Lessons from the DB im getting an error

```
Schwerwiegend:   Generating incomplete JSON
Warnung:   StandardWrapperValve[rest.ApplicationConfig]: Servlet.service() for servlet rest.ApplicationConfig threw exception
java.lang.StackOverflowError
```

I figuered out that its because of the way my Class is build. My Lesson class has a List of questions showns below

```
@Entity
public class Lesson extends EntityWithIntId {


    private String lessonName;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="lessonID",cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Question> questions = new ArrayList<>();

    public Lesson() {
    }


    public Lesson(String lessonName) {
        this.lessonName = lessonName;
    }

 public void addQuestion(Question question) {
        this.questions.add(question);
    }
// getter setter
}
```

Question Class:

```
@Entity
public class Question extends EntityWithIntId {

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "lessonID")
    private Lesson lessonID;
    private String question;

    @ElementCollection
    @MapKeyColumn(name = "answer")
    @Column(name = "solution")
    @CollectionTable(name = "answers", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "questionID"))
    Map<String, Integer> answers = new LinkedHashMap<>();

    public Question() {
    }

    public Question(Lesson lessonID) {
        this.lessonID = lessonID;
    }

    public Question(String question) {
        this.question = question;
    }

    public Question(Lesson lessonID, String question) {
        this.lessonID = lessonID;
        this.question = question;
    }
    public void addAnswer(String answer) {
        this.answers.put(answer, 0);
    }

// getter setter
}
```

So i tested a bit and noticed that if i build the connection bewteen Lesson and Question like this:

```
@Entity
public class Lesson extends EntityWithIntId {

    private String lessonName;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "lessonID")
    private List<Question> questions = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

```
@Entity
public class Question extends EntityWithIntId {

    private int lessonID;
    private String question;

    @ElementCollection
    @MapKeyColumn(name = "answer")
    @Column(name = "solution")
    @CollectionTable(name = "answers", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "questionID"))
    Map<String, Integer> answers = new LinkedHashMap<>();

}
```

Everything works as expected and i get my Json Object. The issue is that i cant change my whole DB structure and my programm only for this. I also have to use JsonB so there is no other choice. 
There has to be a way to get a proper Json object from my current DB.

Here is the @Get method:

```
@GET
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    public Response getAllLesssons() {
        if (super.findAll() != null) {
            return Response.ok(super.findAll()).build();
        } else {
            String message = "Lessons not found!";
            return Response.ok().type(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN).entity(message).build();
        }
    }
```

Anyone knows how to solve this problem?

Comment: Why would changing the entity classes change the database?

Comment: Technically the database will stay the same. But when i want to remove cascade something i was getting errors. I dont remember anymore what the error was but i believe it was something about the persistency

Comment: I do not fully get it. Both versions of `Lesson` have `cascade = CascadeType.ALL`, both version of `Question` have no cascade type set.

Comment: Currently im Creating Objects and fill them with data. At the end i just Persist it for example like this: `Lesson testLesson = new Lesson( "TestLesson");
        Question testQuestion = new Question(testLesson, "TestQuestion");
        testQuestion.addAnswer("Test1");
        testQuestion.addAnswer("Test2");
        testLesson.addQuestion(testQuestion);
        lessonFacade.create(testLesson);`
         but in the changed version i have to create the Lesson in the DB before i can get the ID for the Question otherwise the ID would be null. So i would have to change my whole program .

Comment: Anyway my issue is that i keep getting this error: `Fatal:   Generating incomplete JSON
Warning:   StandardWrapperValve[de.hsos.kbse.util.JAXRSConfiguration]: Servlet.service() for servlet de.hsos.kbse.util.JAXRSConfiguration threw exception
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong number of arguments`

Answer (score 0):

So i solved this issue by removing methods in my Entities which start with get.... and are not returning a Class variable. For examle getLessonById() or something like that. I guess JSON sees them as class variable returner and wants to get data from it. Also Bidirectional relations are causing endless loops so either you use specific annotations to ignore those or you just avoid them completly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use annotation @JsonbTransient (javax.json.bind.annotation.JsonbTransient) to prevent serialization filds causes circle in the object graph.